# Show table on button click

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, repaint

Simply what I want to do is to show some data in `JTable` when user click a button and it works correctly, however something weird is happening.  When I click button at first time nothing happens but when I maximize frame, the table appears!

#### `ActionListener`

```
b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                boolean state = external.isSelected();
                DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(ManhattanTable(values), Headers(values));
                   JTable table = new JTable(model);
                   table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
                   container.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                   table.setVisible(false);
                if(state) {
                    PrintStream out = null;
                    try {
                        out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"));
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.setOut(out);
                    long start= System.currentTimeMillis();
                    Manhattan(values);
                    long end=System.currentTimeMillis();
                    out.println("time: "+(end-start)+" milliseconds");
                    out.println("Number of input data: "+values.size());    
                } else {
                     table.setVisible(true);
                }           
            }
        });
```

Anyone knows, why this strange behaviour?

Comment: 1) `table.setVisible(false);`  That is dubious logic, especially if `state`.  2) Why add the table dynamically, rather than add it at start-up and simply update the model on action?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After adding the table, call [`container.revalidate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#revalidate%28%29)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you create the table and set the properties, but you didn't tell the window to redraw it's components.  When you change the window size, you're forcing it to redraw.